# error with 'find' package

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, find

I can't download anything because it says:

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: warning: 'find' not found in PATH 
or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin 
and /sbin
```

Here's the output of `echo PATH$` (wrapped for readability):

```
/home/dima/bin:/home/dima/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

And the output of `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `echo $PATH` and `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`? Leave me a comment when you're done with that and I'll have a look.

Comment: If using `sudo` directly (rather than an interactive root shell), "root's PATH" likely means the sudo `secure_path`, I think

Comment: @ByteCommander I've added output of theese commands, hope you will check it :)

Comment: @steeldriver sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu, so I don't understand what you've meant to say :(

Comment: Can you also add the output of `$ ls -l $(which find)` please?

Comment: @ByteCommander sorry, I don't know which find is it, it's just 'find' nothing else, and if I type `ls -l $find` it  writes such a big list and it says that it contain 6244 elements

Comment: No, just run the command literally as I wrote it. You don't have to replace anything, it is really just `ls -l $(which find)`.

Comment: @ByteCommander I did it, but the output is the same as the output of `ls -l $find`

Comment: And both `which find` and `ls -l /usr/bin/find` returns nothing then? You could try running `sudo apt install --reinstall findutils`, but probably that won't work because `find` is missing... :-/

Comment: @ByteCommander `ls -l /usr/bin/find` returns that there is no such directory or file, and `sudo apt install --reinstall findutils` returns an error because there's no `find`,  are there any ways to install `find` package without the `find` package?

Comment: @ByteCommander can you please help to fix that error? :)

Comment: Can you download the `findutils` package with `apt download findutils`? In the meanwhile I'll try to find out how we can install it by hand without using `dpkg`.

Comment: @ByteCommander no I can't - first time it have said I don't have acsess to «/home/dima/findutils_4.6.0+git+20160126-2_amd64.deb» and after that running this command returns nothing

Comment: That is really weird. Probably a quick reinstall of the whole system after backing up all of your personal data would be faster and easier than trying to investigate this issue further. I'm afraid I can't really help you there more at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @ByteCommander okay, thank you for try

Comment: @Zanna The error messages `installArchives() failed: dpkg: warning: 'find' not found in PATH or not executable` `dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable` are obviously from `dpkg` and not from `apt`, don't you agree?

Comment: hmm @ByteCommander yeah! I guess whatever is being requested there's no way around `InstallArchives()` call. Seems unlikely to be possible to fix it then. I will delete my comment